multiple `thisArg`s with module function?
There are lots of questions on here about this, but "multiple this args" is getting me answers about how to declare multiple properties under this, which isn't what I'm after. If this is already asked and answered elsewhere, I'll take the pointer!
I have a Prisma extension I'm writing, where the methods I'm creating rely on access to a certain this. But now I'm re-writing the top level of my project as a class, and I want those methods to be able to access the existing this, but also the classThis "this" of the class in which they're declared. Also, I need to be able to pass in this.someVar to methods which are arrow functions and maintaining their own this.
In more detail,
// file: method1.mjs
import { Prisma } from '@prisma/client';

/**
 * @template T
 * @this {T}
 */
export async function method1 (args) {
    const ctx = Prisma.getExtensionContext(this) // this "this" needs to remain

    // I would like to do this, where `classThis` is the "this" of the class that
    // imports this function and uses it as a method
    const test = classThis.sayHello('Hello!');
}

// file myClass.mjs
import { method1 } from 'method1.mjs';

export class MyClass {
    private readonly configArg;

    constructor ( configArg ) {
        this.configArg = configArg;
    }

    sayHello = (greeting) => console.log(greeting);

    method1 = async (args) => {
        // putting in an arrow function and using `call` so Prisma
        // gets the correct `this` in the method defined above
        return await method1.call(this, {
            ...args,
            // also, I think this `this` is no longer the class?
            this.configArg
        });
    }
}

I believe the .call(this is working, but the missing pieces are how do I get method1 to have that this, and a this that lets it call the other methods (e.g., this.sayHello); and in the call to the imported module (which I think has to be an arrow function to get the correct this to prisma), how do I also pass the this.someProp properties from the enclosing class? (configArg in the example).

.getExtensionContext(this) // this "this" needs to remain, The this here is determined by how method1 is called. We can't know what that was since we don't know how you were calling method1 before the class implementation you've shared, currently your code is passing through the class instance as this when you call method1, so it's different to what you had before.

Also, do you really want to be able to do this.sayHello() or are you happy with using it as classThis.sayHello() inside of method1.mjs/method1? If you want this to remain as it was then you'd need to use classThis.sayHello(), as I don't expect that the this had methods like sayHello() on it before, right?

correct. I'm happy with classThis.sayHello(). Previously, it was just importing sayHello directly into the various methods that used it. Re: the first comment, this is an extension (kind of like a library, I guess), and it will be called as a method to a prisma class that someone else instantiates: await somePrismaInstance.someClass.method1(args).

I can add the working, non-class-based, code to the question, if that's useful

I'm not familiar with Prisma specifically, and you didn't provide details on how the method is being called, but this code should demonstrate the techniques you need to use to solve your problem.  I'll even demonstrate how to bring in another special argument in case you need it.


function method1(...args) {
  console.log('`this` is:', this);
  console.log('`args` are:', args);
}

let special = { id: 'special' };

class MyClass {
  constructor () {
      const me = this;
      this.example = function (...args) {
        return method1.call(this, me, special, ...args);
      }
  }
}

const myInstance = new MyClass();
myInstance.id = 'myInstance';
console.log('calling with myInstance');
myInstance.example(1, 2, 3);

console.log('calling with otherInstance');
const otherInstance = { id: 'otherInstance' };
otherInstance.example = myInstance.example;
otherInstance.example(4, 5, 6);



Feel welcome to replace method1 with function method1(me, special, ...args) to help organize the extra arguments.
In this case you can call the method with another instance from the class on which it was defined, and you can have access to the original class and any other special instance.
